# How does one test an AM antenna matching network?

Tags: antenna, radio, impedance-matching, amplitude-modulation

I'm lost. I need to test two AM matching networks. I was not given training and I'm a newborn compared to every other guy in AM Radio out there.

I do own a osciloscope with Bode plot generator but I assume I will need a network analyzer (I've never been in contact with one).

The matching networks are for a 1 kW daytime AM station, 1230 kHz and 1300 kHz.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Cesar! Can you give more details? Are you referring to matching networks at the tower bases? Or a power combiner to allow two transmitters to feed one tower? Is this a single tower, nondirectional station, or a multi-tower, directional setup?

Comment: I'm referring to the matching network at the base of the tower not the power combiner. Yes, there is another station in the same tower. It is a non directional setup (single antenna).

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have pertinent knowledge or experience for the task, the safe route is to hire a broadcast engineering consultant. They have a professional association (SBE) with a [listing by state](https://sbe.org/cce/cce_v2.php#listings).

If that's not possible, here are some tips from an ex-chief engineer (from 50 years ago):

Most issues in a tower base matching network, housed in a metal cabinet out in the elements, aren't solved by impedance tweaking. Do a thorough inspection for arcing, corrosion, dirt, bugs, critters. Capacitors can suffer breakdown (internally or arcing across their insulating case). Roller inductors can suffer corrosion where the contact meets the coil. Listening and watching carefully with the cabinet door open while the station is on the air may expose the problem. Look/listen for arcs at modulation peaks. A  closer inspection will have to be done after the transmitter is shut down.

If you are convinced the matching network needs adjusting, then you may need a network analyzer, which could be rented, or even a VSWR meter for a cruder approach. But you'll need to understand how the adjustments accommodate the two different transmitter frequencies.

Comment: I think I was not clear that enough. The company I work for has two separate towers with two separate matching networks. I followed your advice and cleaned the inside of the case in one of the matching networks as there was rust build up. At the other site I actually found a weak grounding point. The site is on a marsh that floods with the tide and found a corroded ground point, so nothing to do with the matching network. I still will have to look for a manual to perform the procedure once I get a hold of a network analyzer. Thanks for your answer.